# IWD Checkout suite - No Payment method available. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, third-party-module

I have the IWD Checkout suite as Onestepcheckout. But there is a mistake. When you are in checkout you will see "No Payment method available" until the customer enter all informations and choose shipping method. After that Payment Method will show up.

How can i change this?

5 customer write an email everyday about this issue on our site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any theme like Porto then remove "IWD_Opc" form theme root directory.

Comment: This does not sound like a solution. Can you explain why that directory is there, why it should be removed or how that helps?

Comment: Can you be more clear in your explanation please ? what is the `IWD_Opc` why we remove it and what is the impact ?

Comment: Basically for my side its conflicts for extension on theme IWD_Opc when i remove it from theme or child theme IWD Checkout is working fine.